# How to fill a BrowserFrame inside a Panel?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm developing an application which needs to show a web page inside a Panel using a BrowserFrame, but I can't make it fill the entire space inside the Panel that contains the frame.

The main view code is this:

```
public class MyUI extends UI implements ViewDisplay {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3506630583522354337L;
private Panel springViewDisplay;
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

     final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
     root.setSizeFull();
     root.setMargin(true);
     root.setSpacing(true);
     setContent(root);
     final CssLayout navigationBar = new CssLayout();
     navigationBar.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);
     navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("Subir fichero",
                FileUpload.VIEW_NAME));

     navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("Visor grafico", 
             GraphViewer.VIEW_NAME));

     root.addComponent(navigationBar);

      springViewDisplay = new Panel();
      springViewDisplay.setSizeFull();
      root.addComponent(springViewDisplay);
      root.setExpandRatio(springViewDisplay, 1.0f);

}

private Button createNavigationButton(String caption,
        final String viewName) {
    Button button = new Button(caption);
    button.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_SMALL);

     button.addClickListener(
            event -> getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName));
    return button;
}


@Override
public void showView(View view) {
    springViewDisplay.setContent((Component) view);

}

}
```

The view that display the html file is, which is a different java class:

```
@SpringView(name = GraphViewer.VIEW_NAME)
public class GraphViewer extends VerticalLayout implements View {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3328857273907967208L;
public static final String VIEW_NAME = "viewer";
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@PostConstruct
protected void init(){
    ExternalResource page = new ExternalResource("graph.html");

    BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame("", page);
    frame.setSizeFull();

    addComponent(frame);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried to set the GraphViewercomponent size to 100%, but the result I've got is as shown:

[image]
(in red: view size, green: frame size) The code for the previous image is like this:

```
protected void init(){
    ExternalResource page = new  ExternalResource("graph.html");
    BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame("", page);
    setSizeFull();
    addComponent(frame);
}
```

Then if I change the setSizeFull() for frame.setSizeFull(), the frame shows like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Turns out the problem is that iframe element (BrowserFrame) doesn't calculate the height properly.

You can try to solve this with CSS.

Add style name to your frame:

```
BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame("", page);
frame.addStyleName("embedded-frame");
setSizeFull();
```

Then add the following CSS rule:

```
.embedded-frame iframe {
    position: absolute;        
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything, sorry. You better include additional information in the question itself.

Comment: Even better: create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just remove unnecessary code and create dummy components to demonstrate your layout code. This would be super-easy to check and investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to set the `GraphViewer`component size to 100%, but the result I've got is as shown:
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/9rwti31.png) 
(in red: view size, green: frame size)
The code for the previous image is like this:

    protected void init(){
        ExternalResource page = new  ExternalResource("graph.html");
        BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame("", page);
        setSizeFull();
        addComponent(frame);
    }
Then if I change the `setSizeFull()` for `frame.setSizeFull()`, the frame shows like this: 
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LpLBrBw.png)

Comment: @JavierCruz Try to keep both `setSizeFull()` and `frame.setSizeFull()`. Also, please check the borders for `GraphViewer` layout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I've tried to set the `GraphViewer`component size to 100%, but the result I've got is as shown:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25RaN.png)

(in red: view size, green: frame size)
The code for the previous image is like this:

```
protected void init(){
    ExternalResource page = new  ExternalResource("graph.html");
    BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame("", page);
    setSizeFull();
    addComponent(frame);
}
```

Then if I change the `setSizeFull()` for `frame.setSizeFull()`, the frame shows like this:

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA2tD.png)

Comment: You can use "edit" button under your question to add additional information.